# Bindings and introspection for OCaml library

Tags: binding, ocaml, idl

I want to write an OCaml library which will be used by other programing languages like C or even python.

I not sure it's even feasible, and i guess i need to drop some type safety and add runtime checks to the interface for dynamically typed language.

Is it doable ? Is there tools to achieve this goal to auto-generate bindings ? I think stuffs like Corba do not fit well with ocaml ABI, but I may be wrong.

EDIT : by dropping the runtime requirement and using only languages having a llvm frontend, I could use llvm as a common ABI I guess, but it seems tricky.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OCaml has a FFI to [interact with C code](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual033.html). The code for the binding has to be written in C, not in OCaml (which has no direct representation of C values, while C has representations of OCaml values). My advice would be:

1. On the C side, decide what would be the best interface to export that C programmers would like (or Python programmers writing Python bindings starting from your C interface)
2. Define a "low-level layer" on the OCaml side that gets your OCaml value *as close as possible* from the C representation
3. Write some C wrappers to convert from this low-level OCaml representation to your optimal C representation

The reason for step (2) is to have the step (3) as small as possible. Manipulating OCaml values from the C side is a bit painful, in particular you risk getting the interaction with the Garbage Collector wrong, which means segfaults -- plus you don't get any type safety. So the less work you have to do on the C side, the better.

There are some projects to do some of the wrapping work for you. [CamlIDL](http://forge.ocamlcore.org/projects/camlidl/) for example, and I think [Swig](http://www.swig.org/) has some support for OCaml. I have never used those, though, so I can't comment.

If you know to which high-level language you wish to convert your interface to, there may be specialized bridge that don't need a C step. For example there are libraries to interact directly with Python representations (search for Pycaml, not sure how battle-tested their are) or with the Java runtime (the [OCamlJava](http://ocamljava.x9c.fr/) project). A C interface is still a safe bet that will allow other people to create bridges to their own languages.

Answer (score 1):

It is feasible, but you need to understand involved topics, like how the GC works.
Have a look at this: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/manual033.html#toc148

You need to be careful about types in the stub code, but otherwise you can keep type safety.